# Grab every checked items from a custom listview

Tags: java, android

I need to grab every checked items from a ListView with custom items containing a checkbox each in a List<> variable. That ListView is filled dynamically using another List<>.

So far I'm at least trying to get every checked items in my list when clicking on a FAB. I have looked for several solutions, but nothing worked. Sticking to a SparseBooleanArray seems to avoid having any errors and crashes.

Here is the list activity class:

```java
        listViewWithCheckBox.setChoiceMode(listViewWithCheckBox.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listViewWithCheckBox.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, listViewItems));

        FloatingActionButton confirmFAB = findViewById(R.id.inviter_liste_confirm_fab);
        confirmFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checked = listViewWithCheckBox.getCheckedItemPositions();
                System.out.println(listViewWithCheckBox.getCheckedItemPositions());
                System.out.println(listViewWithCheckBox.getCount());
                for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                    if (checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
                        String tag = String.valueOf(listViewWithCheckBox.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i)));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("xxxx", i + " " + tag);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is my custom adapter which implements ListAdapter, excluding empty functions:

```java
    ArrayList<ItemObjet> arrayList;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemObjet> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemObjet subjectData=arrayList.get(position);
        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_people_select_item, null);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });
            TextView tittle=convertView.findViewById(R.id.inviter_list_nom);
            tittle.setText(subjectData.getName());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in a callback for your custom adapter like [this](https://github.com/Kartikkumargujarati/Android-RR/blob/31c2dc92e572c1a2435a6d0f341861ec9105eaac/Networking/app/src/main/java/com/kartik/networking/ui/GistListAdapter.kt#L50).

And then in your activity class, add a global variable to maintain an ArrayList of checked items in the list. Now, override the interface callback when you set the adapter in your activity like [this](https://github.com/Kartikkumargujarati/Android-RR/blob/31c2dc92e572c1a2435a6d0f341861ec9105eaac/Networking/app/src/main/java/com/kartik/networking/ui/GistListFragment.kt#L49).